# How to get the name of unnumbered section into headings?

Tags: sectioning

I use

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
```

then

```
\pagestyle{headings}
```

and I want `\section*{name of the section}` in my headings.
How to do it?

Comment: hi and welcome, If you want it to appear in the table of contents as well, have a look at [unnumberedtotoc](https://github.com/johannesbottcher/unnumberedtotoc).

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you use a KOMA class which provides the command `\addsec` which produces an unnumbered section, but it is inserted in the ToC and you have headings for that?

Example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\addsec{Unnumbered section}
\lipsum[1-20]

\section{Numbered section}
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course the headings can be customized as you want, as with `fancyhdr` package.

Answer (score 2):

[Edited to take comments by @daleif and @Johannes_B into account.]

Here is how section 9 of the `fancyhdr` manual ends.

[Note: To get the manual under Linux or OS X, do `texdoc fancyhdr` in a terminal.]

> As a final remark you should also note that the `*` forms of the
>   `\chapter` etc. commands do *not* call the mark commands.
>   So if you want your preface to set the header info but not be
>   numbered nor be put in the table of contents, you must issue
>   the `\markboth` command yourself, e.g.
>
> ```
> \chapter*{Preface\markboth{Preface}{}}
> ```
>
> Entering the `\markboth` command inside the `\chapter*` insures
>   that the mark will not be separated from the title by a page break.
>   Of course with `\chapter*` this wouldn’t be a problem if you put
>   the mark command after the chapter title, as the `\chapter*` command
>   starts at a new page.
>   However with a `\section*` it could be dangerous to say:
>
> ```
> \section*{Preface}
> \markboth{Preface}{}
> ```
>
> as a page break may occur between the two commands.

This suggests that two possible ways to do what you want are:

1.

```
\section*{Flowers\markboth{Flowers}{Flowers}}
```

2.

```
\section*{Flowers}
\markboth{Flowers}{Flowers}
```

and although the `fancyhdr` recommends the first one,
there are strong arguments for the second one.

The first option, although recommended by the manual,
is arguably more dangerous, as some document classes or packages
will insert the argument of `\section*` in the table of contents,
so the header of some table of contents pages could be changed
when the toc entry for your `\section*` appears.

With the second possibility, the possible drawback, mentioned
by the `fancyhdr` manual, is that a page break could occur
just after the section title and thus the `\markboth` instruction
would only take effect on the next page. The danger is limited,
in that a page break just after a title section is quite rare,
and also even if that happened I would be happy with the header
being changed only from the next page on.

To totally control that, you could `\renewcommand` the
`\section*` command to insert the `\markboth` command
in its definition at an appropriate place to make it
take effect exactly from the start of the section title.

Comment: Hmm, I'd say that `\section*{...}\markboth{...}{...}` is cleaner. Remember that some classes actually write `\section*` to the TOC.

Comment: @daleif Out of curiosity, which class does that?

Comment: @daleif: I would have thought like you but I quoted the advice of the `fancyhdr` manual (I added the corresponding excerpt).

Comment: But @daleif is right in saying that some packages *take* the argument and do stuff with it. I guess yo don't want the mark suddenly appear in another section.

Comment: \documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{nameref}
\begin{document}
\chapter*{This is the test\markboth{LABEL}{LABEL}}
\label{label}
\blindtext[10]
\chapter{Donald}
\blindtext[10]
\nameref{label}
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}

Comment: @Johannes_B, nice example. As an example of a class that adds `\section*` to the TOC: `amsart`.

Comment: @daleif Didn't know that, thank you :-)