# Displaying long names of sections when using in table of content

Tags: table-of-contents

I need LaTeX to display long names of chapters/sections when using `\tableofcontents` and `\section[short]{long}` in `book` document class.

Right now it shows only short name and I need it for headers.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. The `book` class does not provide that feature. The KOMA-script equivalent `scrbook` does. A simple workaround would be to avoid the `[short]` form completely and set the header entry by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Staying with the `book` class, you can use:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{A chapter title}

\lipsum[1-3]

\section{A long long long long long long long long long long long long long
  long long long long long long long long long long long title}%
\sectionmark{Short section title}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image: Page 1]

---

[image: Page 2]

---

[image: Page 3]

---

[image: Page 4]

---

[image: Page 5]

You may also want to consult the [fancyhdr](https://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) documentation and `\markboth` as well as `\markright`, for example [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222380/how-to-get-the-name-of-unnumbered-section-into-headings).